# Implement a window as a page in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have lots of windows in my project. Now I am thinking to convert it into pages then then implement it into frame navigation.
Is there any way to convert all the windows into frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very simple way : build a new page then set the page content = the window content. But you loose some properties (width, height) some events loader (Loaded,...), and obviously some operations are not allowed on pages.
If you want to try without taking too much risk on your project, take a few windows (W1,W2,W3), then create the pages P1,P2,P3. Now create W1', W2', W3', which are just a Window with a frame linked to P1, P2, P3 respectively. This way you can check if your app can be 'translated' to page logic and begin testing navigation while still having full functionnalities for the Windowed version of your application. Note that if your application follows MVVM, the translation 'should' be easy.